# Wrong requestMapping send it by a form

Tags: java, spring

I would like to know how can I solve this problem, let me explain: I want to create a search bar and send the user to a jsp view with the results. I created in my controller the next method :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/search={productName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView getProducteByName(@PathVariable("productName") String productName) {

        ModelAndView modelview = new ModelAndView("/productSearch");  
        List productsByName = productService.getProductByName(productName);                  
        modelview.addObject("productsByName", productsByName );    
        return modelview;
```

And I have a form in a jsp file like this:

```jsp
    <!-- Search form -->
<form class="form-inline md-form form-sm mt-0" method="get" >
   <i class="fas fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   <input class="form-control form-control-sm ml-3 w-75" type="text" placeholder="Search" name="search"
                aria-label="Search">
</form>
```

The problem is when I put anything to search in the bar search, it works put it puts me a `?` in the url, so the controller doesn't understand the requestMapping.

Example: `http://localhost:8080/projectbotigabio/search=potato`
and it puts me: `http://localhost:8080/projectbotigabio/?search=potato`
I've tried a lot of things, including trying to putting as a method "post" instead of "get", but it doesn't work... any solution?

Comment: Can you try @RequestMapping(value = "/search/{productName}"

Answer (score 0):

Web browsers only support 3 kinds of form submission:

- `method="get"`

  Every form value is added to the URL using `?name=value&name=value&...`
- `method="post"`

  Every form value is added to POST with content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and content `name=value&name=value&...`
- `method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"`

  The POST request has content type `multipart/form-data`, and the content is a multipart with each part being a form value.

Web browsers cannot build the URL you want, so you have to do it yourself, i.e. prevent the web browser from sending the POST request, and send your own request using Ajax. If that's what you want, put on your learning hat and start studying how that works.

I recommend that you stop trying to use a non-standard URL syntax, and use the standard `GET` processing.

Either way, I suggest you learn more about how HTML forms work, before you try deviating from the standards any further.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explaination! Then I'll try to use Ajax...